# UTF-8 characters in a pdfcell itext

Tags: java, android

I've a problem with UTF-8 characters in a PdfCell. The result is bad. For example in my pdf i've "DiplÃ´me" instead of "Diplôme". Also with "garÃ§on(s)" instead of "garçons"
I've try to look at solution in Stackoverflow without success.
I've you an idea to solve my problem
Think you very much
Best regards
Georges

```
 String pdfPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
               file = new File(pdfPath, "PlateauxU7.pdf");
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PlateauxU7Activity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                       PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
               Document pdfDocument = new Document();
               pdfDocument.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
               pdfDocument.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

               FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

               try {
                   PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, new FileOutputStream(file));
                   pdfWriter.setLanguage("FR");
               } catch (DocumentException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

               pdfDocument.open();
               BaseFont baseFontArial = BaseFont.createFont("res/font/arial.ttf", "UTF-8", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

               Font regularReport = new Font(baseFontArial, 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
               Font regularReportBold = new Font(baseFontArial, 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
               Font titleReport = new Font(baseFontArial, 16, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
               Font titleReportBlanc = new Font(baseFontArial, 16, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE);
```

Comment: Where does the data such as "Diplôme" come from?

Comment: ligne3Pdf = "Dirigeant : " + wdirigeant + " Licence no : " + wlicence + " Diplôme : " + wdiplome;

Comment: Have you checked that the font file you are using actually has the right letters at the code points you are using?

Comment: I copied the font from my pc,perhaps it's the problem?

Comment: for information I've the same problem using BaseFont.HELVETICA or BaseFont.COURIER!!

Comment: I've solved th problem using : BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now the report pdf is correct. I don't know what is CP1250 but it resolve my problem